# How do I declare shared attributes for Rails fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, yaml, dry, fixtures

I'm trying to get started with (Rails) testing, using fixtures and MiniTest.
The app is evolving, so it's likely that additional attributes are integrated in the models later on.
Is there a way to declare "default" attributes or kind of base fixtures that are used in all other fixtures?

For Example:

```
base_user:
  name: testy testicle
  mail: some_mail@example.com
  gender: male

user1:
  avatar: some_avatar #add
  admin: false #add

user2:
  admin:true #add
  gender: female #overwrite
```

So *user1* & *user2* share the attributes of *base_user* ?
Perhaps even share the attributes and overwrite if necessary?

I want to declare base attributes to pass validations etc. and just want to declare special attributes in the other fixtures.
When new attributes get neccessary I could add them to the base_fixture, instead of updating all fixtures for the model..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use YAMLs Anchors and References facility. This would look like this:

```
base_user: &BASE_USER # <- Declare an anchor named BASE_USER
  name: # etc.

user1:
  <<: *BASE_USER # <- Reference the anchor, bringing all the attributes of base user into user1
  avatar: # etc.
```

Comment: One point to be aware of on this is that the `base_user` will still be created in the database. So if `base_user` doesn't include any attributes that are required via database constraints you'll get an error from the database at runtime of the test suite.

Comment: definitely useful for shared attributes. Would it be possible to overwrite e.g. gender if it's declared in base_user and user1 ?

Comment: That should work just fine. If you give `user1` the attribute `gender: female` after you reference the base object, that is the value you'll get in `user1`, even if the base object already had a `gender` attribute.